# Node layer in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

Does anybody know if and how in the following minimal example :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}


\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,backgrounds}



\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node(fin){$\square$};
    \path[draw](fin)--node [midway, above] {\textit{4 mois}}(10,0)node(repere) {$\square$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I could have my second node easily put the same way like the first (ie. with the little indent between the node and the line)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me explain what happens with your code.

```
\node(fin){$\square$};
```

places a node centered at `(0,0)` which contains `$\square$`. This is the square which is drawn, not the node itself. Every node has certain `inner sep` between its contents and node's border. If you want to see the real border, use option `draw` (`\node[draw](fin)...`)

```
\path[draw](fin)--node [midway, above] {\textit{4 mois}}(10,0) node[draw=red,right](repere) {$\square$};
```

Now a line between `(fin.center)` and `(10,0)` is drawn. Although this line starts at `(fin.center)` it's not drawn until it reaches `fin` border. This is the gap you see in your scheme.

And once the line is finished at point `(10,0)` a new node is drawn centered on this coordinate. This is the reason for placing right square over the line.

If you want to keep same distance, `repere` border should be when line finishes, which means anchoring it to `west` anchor (`right` option).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw=red](fin){$\square$};
    \path[draw](fin)--node [midway, above] {\textit{4 mois}}(10,0) node[draw=red,right](repere) {$\square$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]